# Why do I get the error message "start_time is not defined"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I am getting and error on line 20 (pulse_duration = end_time - start_time) that says:

> ```
> NameError: name 'start_time' is not defined
> ```

```
import gpiozero
import time

TRIG = 23
ECHO = 24

trigger = gpiozero.OutputDevice(TRIG)
echo = gpiozero.DigitalInputDevice(ECHO)

trigger.on()
time.sleep(0.00001)
trigger.off()

while echo.is_active == False:
        start = time.time()

while echo.is_active == True:
        end = time.time()

pulse_duration = end_time - start_time

distance = 34300 * (pulse_duration/2)

round_distance = round(distance, 1)

print("Distance: ", round_distance)
```

Comment: Because it seems like you haven't defined a variable `start_time`... you did define a variable `start` though... perhaps you meant that instead?

Comment: You also did not define `end_time` but you defined `end`.

Answer (score 0):

Because both `end_time` and `start_time` have not been defined in your code. You named them `start` and `end`. Another issue you'll encounter is the scope of where those variables are defined. Define them outside of the loop with defaults.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above it seems as though you are calling other variables that are not defined and you'd run into the issue of no default values. Try this:

```
 import gpiozero
 import time

 TRIG = 23
 ECHO = 24

 trigger = gpiozero.OutputDevice(TRIG)
 echo = gpiozero.DigitalInputDevice(ECHO)

 trigger.on()
 time.sleep(0.00001)
 trigger.off()
 start = 0
 end = 0
 while echo.is_active == False:
    start = time.time()

 while echo.is_active == True:
    end = time.time()

 pulse_duration = end - start

 distance = 34300 * (pulse_duration/2)

 round_distance = round(distance, 1)

 print("Distance: ", round_distance)
```